# Can a function with four fractions be solved?

Tags: calculus

$g(x^2+{\sqrt {x}})$ when $g(t) = \frac{8}{t}-6t$.

I have $\frac{8}{x^2} - \frac{6x^2}{1} + \frac{8}{\sqrt{x}} - \frac{6}{\sqrt{x}}$.

What next?

Comment: This is unreadable.

Comment: Please reformat. I think I know what you mean by "/sqrt" (use "\sqrt"), but I don't understand "{8}{t}".

Comment: What do you mean by solved? Do you want to find the zeros of $g(x^2+\sqrt{x})$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: What you have here is not $g\bigl(x^2+\sqrt x\bigr),$ but rather $g\bigl(x^2\bigr)+g\bigl(\sqrt x\bigr).$ Do you see why?

You ***cannot*** "split apart" the problem, as you seem to want to do. To see why, let's consider the case that $x=1$. On the one hand, $1^2=1$ and $\sqrt1=1,$ so when $x=1$ we have $$g(x^2)=g(1)=\frac81+6\cdot1=8+6=14,$$ and similarly $g(\sqrt x)=g(1)=14,$ so $$g\bigl(x^2\bigr)+g\bigl(\sqrt x\bigr)=14+14=28.$$ However, $$g\bigl(x^2+\sqrt x\bigr)=g(2)=\frac82+6\cdot 2=4+12=16,$$ which isn't the same at all!

The mistake you're making is a *very* common one for people to make when first meeting function notation--after all, we can distribute multiplication like $2(x+y)=2(x)+2(y),$ so shouldn't we be able to distribute $g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$? Unfortunately, the answer is "no," in general. Think of the function $g$ not as a number, but more as a machine--in thus case, if you stick an appropriate $t$ into one end of the function, it spits $\frac8t+6t$ out the other end. We abbreviate this output with the label "g(t)"; it just means put $t$ into $g$ and see what pops out.

And just as with machines, it sometimes makes a difference when and how you put things in. For example, say our machine heated something significantly for ten minutes while stirring it. If we added water and soup mix together, then put it in our machine, we could end up with hot soup. If we put them in our machine *separately* and then added the results together, we'd end up with charred soup mix drifting in water!

Answer (score 0):

$g(t) = \frac 8t - 6t\\
g(x^2 + \sqrt x) = \frac 8{x^2 + \sqrt x} - 6(x^2 + \sqrt x)$

And I would be content to say that you are done here.  There really isn't much reason to keep simplifying.  Nor is there anything to "solve."

As for the rest of what you have...
 you cannot split up the fraction.  i.e.

$\frac 8{x^2 + \sqrt x} \ne \frac 8{x^2} + \frac 8{\sqrt x}$